# "ImportError: No module named..." when importing my own module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, pythonanywhere

I am trying to import a module and I keep getting an ImportError.

In the PortfolioStatus.py file I have the following code which imports the share_data class from the share_data.py module

 `from Shares.share_data import share_data`

I am getting the following error:

```
File "/home/lucasamos/FYP/Shares/Communication/PortfolioStatus.py", line 3, in <module>
from Shares.share_data import share_data
ImportError: No module named Shares.share_data
```

To make things more confusing this works fine on my local machine but I am hosting on PythonAnywhere and this is where I am getting the error

My file hierarchy is show in the image below

[image: File hierarchy]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the working directory in your run configuration? That will get added to `sys.path`. If you make it the project directory (by leaving it blank) `Shares` should be importable.

Comment: Check out the [detailed guide to debugging sys.path and import issues on PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK so I finally worked it out. 
As indicated by a few of the answers I needed to add my root folder to the system path.

In the end this is what I did:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/lucasamos/FYP")
```

Comment: hooray!  for anyone else with similar problems, there's a [detailed guide to sys.path and import errors on pythonanywhere](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError) in the docs

Comment: adding the ROOT folder solved it for me! Important that its the FULL path!! thanks lucas

Answer (score 11):

you should try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../Shares/templates")
import share_data
```

It adds your templates folder to the list of path python is checking for modules.

Comment: The `share_data.py` file isn't in the templates folder, it's in the `Shares` folder. I just added `Shares` to the path however and that didn't work :(

Comment: My bad, I miss the closed folder. Try adding the complete path instead of the relative path , e.g "/home/YourName/PycharmProjects/FYP/Shares"

Comment: You need to add the containing directory, not the package itself.

Comment: @PeterWood could you elaborate? I'm afraid I'm a bit of a python n00b

Answer (score 4):

Add empty `__init__.py` on one level with `manage.py` file.

Such inclusion of `__init__.py` file indicates to the Python interpreter that the directory should be treated as a Python package.

Comment: @MattO'Brien thanks for your comment, sure i would add some explanations for that answer. Have a good day)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your Shares directory is not in your PYTHONPATH.

See this article about using PYTHONPATH:
https://users-cs.au.dk/chili/PBI/pythonpath.html

Excerpt:

> Often however, you will need to import a module not located in the same directory as the main program. Continuing the example above, assume you're writing a program located in ~/PBI/ which needs to include mymodule.py.
>
> In order for the Python interpreter to find your module, you need to tell it where to look. You can do that by setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH. Depending on the shell program you use (e.g., xterm), this is done in one of two ways.
>
> Bash:
>
> export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/users/[your username]/PBI/Modules/

Comment: When adding external links (which might at some point in the future become broken) it is customary to also edit the relevant part into your answer.